# How to fix those Typescript-Eslint warnings converting a working javascript Svelte 3 store?

Tags: javascript, typescript, svelte, svelte-3

I'm using Svelte 3, Typescript and this code:

- loginStore.ts:

```
import { writable } from "svelte/store";

const store = () => {
  const state = {
    isLoggedIn: false,
  };

  const { subscribe, update } = writable(state);

  const methods = {
    OnInit() {
      this.Login();
    },

    Login() {
      if (window.localStorage.isLoggedIn) {
        update(() => {
          state.isLoggedIn = true;
          return state;
        });
      }
    },

    async Logout() {
      await doLogout();
      update(() => {
        state.isLoggedIn = false;
        return state;
      });
    },
  };

  return {
    subscribe,
    ...methods,
  };
};

export default store();
```

But `@typescript-eslint` is giving me these errors:

1. `Avoid referencing unbound methods which may cause unintentional scoping of this` on line:

   ```
   const { subscribe, update } = writable(state)
   ```
2. `Unsafe member access .Login on an any value` on line:

   ```
   this.Login()
   ```
3. `Unsafe call of an any typed value` on line:

   ```
   this.Login()
   ```

And if I use this store in a component like this:

- App.svelte

```
<script>
  import loginStore from '../stores/auth'

  loginStore.OnInit()
</script>

{#if $loginStore.isLoggedIn}
  I'm logged in!
{:else}
  I'm NOT logged in!
{/if}
```

it complains with `Unsafe member access .isAuthenticated on an any value.` on line:

```
{#if $loginStore.isAuthenticated}
```

How can I fix these warnings?

I have a lot of old stores like this one to convert to Typescript.